# How do I transpile an *expression* with babel?

Tags: babeljs

Given the following:

```js
require('babel-core').transform('3').code
```

Is there a way to get this to return `3` (an expression) instead of `3;` (a statement)?

I've tried:

- Searching the web and various sites for 'babel expression', 'babel transpile expression', and the like.
- Passing `(3)`, but that also was transformed into `3;`.
- Poking the babel internals to figure out what's going on, but I don't know enough about how it works to sort this out.
- Passing the option `minified: true`, which claims to remove the trailing semicolon but doesn't actually seem to do anything.

Right now I'm using `.replace(/;$/, '')`, which *works* but seems absurd and error-prone.

Comment: What if you passed in an expression that had to be converted into multiple statements? Babel doesn't provide guarantees like what you appear to be looking for. Plus without the full context of the file around the expression, Babel has no way of handling scoping, like making sure it doesn't generate a variable name that is already in use around the expression.

Comment: @loganfsmyth What sort of expression would get converted into statements? I can't think of any off the top of my head. Also, wouldn't that also cause problems for e.g. a program which set a variable to the value of the expressions?
I don't need to worry about scoping since these are standalone expressions, they don't have any context.

Comment: What if you do `({x: {y, z}} = foo)`? That currently needs a temporary variable to store `foo.x`, so that variable declaration would be split out. e.g. `var _tmp; _tmp = foo.x; y = _tmp.y; z = _tmp.z;`. You could put the assignments in one expression if you wanted, but the variable declaration needs to be separate.

Comment: I guess it could add a wrapper IIFE but that'd be pretty expensive at runtime.

Comment: @loganfsmyth IIFE is the obvious answer, but it can also be compiled to `(_foo = foo, _foo$x = _foo.x, y = _foo$x.y, z = _foo$x.z, _foo)`--and this is in fact what babel does if you use it as an expression. ([repl demo](http://babeljs.io/repl/#presets=es2015&code=x%3D(%7Bx%3A%20%7By%2C%20z%7D%7D%20%3D%20foo)))

Comment: Right, but that Babel output also includes two `var` statements :) You are right that the IIFE is an option, but it'd be slower for non-expression code, and unless we handle the general case with an IIFE, we'd have to special-case every transform with expression vs file, which is unlikely. You'd be better off treating your expression as a file, then wrapping the output in a function yourself.

Answer (score 4):

@loganfsmyth provided the missing link on [BabelJS.slack](https://babeljs.slack.com/archives/C0DFJT81H/p1492555361558530) -- `parserOpts.allowReturnOutsideFunction`. Here's the code I came up with:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');

let script = 'return ((selector, callback) => Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), callback))("#main table a.companylist",a => a.innerText)';

let transform = babel.transform(script, {
    ast: false,
    code: true,
    comments: false,
    compact: true,
    minified: true,
    presets: [
        ['env', {
            targets: {
                browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 Firefox versions', 'last 2 Chrome versions', 'last 2 Edge versions', 'last 2 Safari versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'IE >= 8'],
            }
        }]
    ],
    parserOpts: {
        allowReturnOutsideFunction: true,
    }
});

let code = `return function(){${transform.code}}()`;
```

Output:

```
return function(){"use strict";return function(selector,callback){return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector),callback)}("#main table a.companylist",function(a){return a.innerText});}()
```

My input script looks a bit funny just because of how I generated it, but you can see that it transformed those arrow expressions into regular functions and the whole thing is still an expression.

N.B. you may want to modify that last line to something like

```
let code = `(function(){${transform.code}})()`;
```

depending on your needs. I needed mine to be `return`ed.